# AVE: Access Violation @adress in module: DELPHI7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, access-violation

This is the handled onchange procedure of 81 TEdit-s (MyEdit[bx,by,x,y]) dynamically created and grouped in a 4 dimensional massive. For now I'm trying to program the Edits to accept only 1 digit. The "only digits" part works normal, but "only 1 digit" part gives Access Violation Error (AVE). The code:

```
procedure TForm1.OnHandleChange(Sender: TObject);
var
bx,by,x,y,len : Integer;
begin
bx:=(sender as TEdit).tag div 1000;
by:=(sender as TEdit).tag div 100-10*bx;
x:=(sender as TEdit).tag div 10-100*bx-10*by;
y:=(sender as TEdit).tag-bx*1000-by*100-x*10;
{*The line below gives the error*} 
if not (MyEdit[bx,by,x,y].text[1] in ['1'..'9']) then MyEdit[bx,by,x,y].text:='';
MyEdit[bx,by,x,y].SelStart:=length(MyEdit[bx, by, x,y].text);
if length(MyEdit[bx, by, x,y].text) >1
              then MyEdit[bx,by,x,y].text:=MyEdit[bx,by,x,y].text[2];
end;
```

The program executes and works although there is an AVE. Everytime I input a letter instead of a digit - the error comes, I click ok, and program does the job. But it is necessary to remove that error. Is there any way?

Comment: oops, sorry for a little mistake. The "only 1 digit" part works normal, but "only digits" part gives the error.. See the line starting with IF NOT. thanks

Comment: It would be better to test for digits in the OnKey event of the edit box.

Comment: @Keith - he should not use any of key events at all! there is TMaskEdit that just does it out of the box.

Comment: @Arioch, make an answer rather than posting so many comments, please.

Comment: @Arioch, I've seen many answers starting with *as a complement to someones answer...* without copying the content of the answer. So I think it's perfectly fine to post your own answer only with additional information saying it's a complement to someones post.

Comment: @HasanA. don't forget to tag Delphi version! or you would get answers for XE2 and such, that would not work in D7

Answer (score 3):

`MyEdit[bx,by,x,y].text[1]` makes the assumption that the edit box text is non-empty, i.e. has at least 1 single character. When the edit box text is empty, the `Text` property is the empty string and accessing the first character leads to an access violation.

I note that you are setting the edit box text to the empty string explicitly, and of course the user can do so. So you certainly have to guard for that eventuality.

Solve the problem by checking whether or not the edit box is empty.

```
var
  Text: string;
....
Text := MyEdit[bx,by,x,y].Text;
if (Length(Text)=1) and (Text[1] in ['1'..'9']) then
  ....
```

---

The other possible candidate for an access violation is if `MyEdit[bx,by,x,y]` results in an out of bounds access of the array. Perhaps your mathematics with the Tag field is all messed up. It looks pretty weird to me.

As I state below, `Sender as TEdit` would appear to make more sense here.

---

More general comments:

- You really need to separate the presentation, i.e. the GUIm from the underlying data. You really don't want to be solving with a 4D array of visual controls as your input data.
- Don't keep repeating `(Sender as TEdit).tag`. Read that value once into a local variable. Or perhaps store `(Sender as TEdit)` into a local variable.
- Why are you calculating `bx`, `by`, `x` and `y` at all? Surely `Sender as TEdit` is all you need.
- Even if you do have to calculate these, don't keep repeating yourself by writing `MyEdit[bx,by,x,y]` more than once. Store that reference into a local variable and use that in any subsequent reference.
- If you need to calculate `bx`, `by`, `x` and `y` from `Tag`, don't do it inline in an event handler. Put that calculation in a dedicated helper method. And likewise a dedicated helper method that goes in the opposite direction. And test that those functions are indeed inverses of each other.

To give you an example, those helpers could look like this:

```
procedure PackCoordinates(const bx, by, x, y: Byte; out Tag: Integer);
begin
  LongRec(Tag).Bytes[0] := bx;
  LongRec(Tag).Bytes[1] := by;
  LongRec(Tag).Bytes[2] := x;
  LongRec(Tag).Bytes[3] := y;
end;

procedure UnpackCoordinates(const Tag: Integer; out bx, by, x, y: Byte);
begin
  bx := LongRec(Tag).Bytes[0];
  by := LongRec(Tag).Bytes[1];
  x := LongRec(Tag).Bytes[2];
  y := LongRec(Tag).Bytes[3];
end;
```

Comment: @Arioch'The I don't follow your comment. Please elaborate.

Comment: ok I corrected the things you all said here, thanks. But the main problem is still here, I tried David's code, error still comes.

Comment: calling .text here and there instead of caching is even more expensive operation than `as` and array reference `MyEdit[bx,by,x,y]`. Interactions with OS are to be minimized as 1st optimization step. Local TEXT variable is needed.

Comment: @Arioch'The Performance is not a consideration here. It's all about making the code readable and maintainable and correct. Following the principle of DRY. The user is hitting the keyboard. Just imagine how many CPU cycles that takes. Obsessing on performance is not what's needed here.

Comment: @TLama If the edit instances were not all created, the `OnChange` handler would not fire because there would be no control. Surely `Sender as TEdit` is what's needed here. All that `div` math is just weird.

Comment: Even considering DRY, redundant accessing Text is redundant. And while speed is not worth re-factoring code it still is worth understanding and writing effective code from beginning.

Comment: @Arioch'The I agree. Note the storing of `Text` to a local var as the very first part of my answer!

Comment: @HasanA. Please see my various updates for more ideas. My guess is that your maths is wonky and the array access is out of bounds. But I'd still be using `Sender as TEdit` and forgetting about the `Tag` math. I don't think you need the `Tag` here. If you need it anywhere, do it as per my packing functions.

Comment: @David well, sources hold it but no highlight is given in description. So i missed it and so would many casual readers

Answer (score 0):

Why need that handler at all ? Just set the mask of `TMaskEdit`. '9' seems to be what u need.

- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.MaskUtils.TEditMask
- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Mask.TCustomMaskEdit.EditMask

---

AV reason was spot by David. But at TLama suggestion i bring my comments to an answer.

---

There is also [DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). Don't do calculations time and again. Do it once and remember the result.

- Because that is faster, sometimes much faster (asking TEdit.text is asking Windows GDI service, that is not just reading a regular variable).
- Because that is more reliable - copying the same forumla here and there you may make typo and end u[ with different formulas.
- Because that is more future-proof. Would you one day change the formula - you would have to make it in only one place, not search all its occurences.
- As David pointed, `Sender` is already your edit. No point in searching for it again!

---

Do not multiply and delete - those operations are expensive. Especially when you delete by 10 instead of [2,4,8,16,...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_two#The_first_96_powers_of_two)

And just do not divide anyway - you can naturally split values using typecast here.

---

Using 4D array is very strange. Very. Do you really need it ?

---

All in all it boils down to

```
type TTagSplit = packed record 
                        case byte of
                             0: (Tag: integer);   
                             1: (bx, by, x, y: byte);  end; 

procedure CreatingEdits...
var tt: TTagSplit; e: TEdit;
begin
    for ... do begin
        e := TEdit.Create(MainForm);
        ....
        tt.bx := ...; tt. by := ....
        e.Tag := tt.Tag;
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.OnHandleChange(Sender: TObject);
var
    bx,by,x,y,len : Integer;
    e : TEdit; txt: string;
    tt: TTagSplit;
begin
    e := Sender as TEdit;
    tt.Tag := e.Tag;
    bx := tt.bx; by := ....
    // Here you do not need those bx and rest - just demo how to get them

    txt := e.Text;

    if length(txt) > 1 
       then e.Text := txt[2] 
       else
         if txt > '' then 
            if not (txt[1]  in ['1'..'9'])
               then e.Text := '';
end;
```

---

But bringing resume - just using TMaskEdit would made all that code not needed. TMaskedit would itself check for content to be one digit or empty. The only thing to check would be that digit is not zero.

---

And the cherry to top that pie - you don't need 81 editboxes at all! You should just put one single `TStringGrid` set to 9x9 size.

Comment: Well Arioch I need 4 dimensions, because while checking sudoku we need to check lines, rows, and 3x3 blocks. Thats why I grouped them in 4dim. lets say i want to check the fifth 3x3 block that stands in the most middle of the area. There is no way to explain program to group them by 9 3x3 and check for solution.

Comment: Then you need special 1D arrays for those lines, rows and blocks (there are also diagonals AFAIR). And probably arrays of Integer rather than TEdit. What exactly and how would you search for in that mega-array ?

Comment: `TTagSplit` is a good idea, but it already exists. It is SysUtils.LongRec.

Comment: My worktime is nearly over, I will follow the thread in home. Thanks for helping

Comment: @David thanks, But when performing low-level tricks, i'd prefer to see my types rather than search documentation and be nervous about future updates (though particularly LongRec would hardly be changed ever). Though generally you might be right. Also i made them having context meaningful names instead of just generic [0],[2] etc, when you can easily forget meanings of indices and misuse them.

Comment: Most funny thing to me seems - why no one suggested him to put one StringGrid instead of 81 editboxes? :-)

Comment: @HasanA assuming the same ordering of columns for blocks and digits, what would `MyEdit[1,1,9,9]` correspond to ? `MyEdit[3,3,1,1]` ?

Comment: I'm online, wow you have plenty of suggestions here :D
@Arioch box[7,7] in my system would be box[3,3,1,1]. similarly [3,3,3,3] is [9,9]. I don't know much about delphi, i just make programs trusting on complex math-l function and procedures that's why my programs are so ineffective.

Comment: Well, i'd just create `array [1..9, 1..9] of byte` for a field and then added logical grouping as next layer. But i see your way of grouping now.